# Excel macro row variable

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I am trying to make an excel macro. How can i make rows variable? It must increase as A6,A7,A8...
I know making colums variable but can't do it for rows.
Here are a few lines from the code.

```
For profnum = 1 To 100
    Range("A6").Select.Offset(1 + (profnum - 1) * 1, 0).Select
```

And i have over 100 graph profiles. Every profile has x and y values. And i changed  124(number of x and y values) as 504 as seen below. But repeating that 200 times or 500 times is very hard and takes too long time. How can i make it by a macro?

```
=SERİLER("file44.txt";main_excel!$ED$4:$ED$504;main_excel!$EE$4:$EE$504;45)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of "making columns variable"? Also, am I wrong in thinking `Range("A6").Select.Offset(1 + (profnum - 1) * 1, 0).Select` from above could simply be rewritten as `Range("A6").Offset(profnum, 0).Select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `Offset` method to return a range object which is implicitly one column wide, but you're iterating by rows.  This is the first argument in the `Offset` method:

`object.Offset(row_offset, column_offset)`

So, simply make a small revision to your code by swapping the position of the arguments:

`Range("A6").Offset(0, 1 + (profnum - 1) * 1).Select`

To keep the row constant, but the column varies, the following loop will select `A6`, then `B6`, then `C6`, then `D6`, etc.

```
For i = 1 to 100
    Range("A6").Offset(0, profnum).Select
Next
```

To keep the column constant, but the row varies, the following loop will select `A6`, `A7`, `A8`, etc.:

```
For i = 1 to 100
    Range("A6").Offset(profnum, 0).Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable rows?

Do you mean dynamic?

```
Dim LstRw As Long
LstRw = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```